# How to modify jhipster entity after starting development

Tags: jhipster

Hi all I'm trying to develop an application using jhipster and i have some questions. Can i modify my entities after starting development i'mean if i add some new attributes to my entity and import the new jdl file will this operation delete the custom code added by me (back end and front end). if yes what is the best way to modify the entity and save my customization and the old data in the database?
Thanks All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use git to merge your custom code with updated generated code, consider JHipster as a team mate who makes changes to your code on its own git branch and then merge its changes with yours.

Use liquibase:diff to create Liquibase migrations that modifies your schema incrementally rather than modifying existing migrations and implement manual code in them for existing data migration. See [JHipster documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#database-updates) and Liquibase documentation too.

Comment: Do you know how to add a class as a field rather than a primitive? For instance, add a "User" to your "BankAccount"

Comment: Your example looks more like a relationship to another entity which is supported by JHipster unless you meant to define your field as an `@Embeddable` which is not supportted by the generator and so in this case you must manually modify generated code.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaël Marziou says, git is a must have tool to work with on your project.

If you update your entities, you can import the jdl file one more time but read carefully the sub-generator output, it show you the modified/conflicted files and ask you if you want to override existing files or not.

But, I'm looking for tricks and solutions for deleting too.